Mongoose не подключается к MongoDB
Короче смотрите, я пытаюсь подключить бд к MongoDB Compass, через Mongoose
Вот код mongoose.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

/* Connnect to our database */
// Get the URI of the local database, or the one specified on deployment.
const mongoURI =
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/volunteer-help";

mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error connecting to mongodb. Timeout reached.");
  });

module.exports = { mongoose }; // Export the active connection.

Но почему-то модель самой базы данных не появляется в MongoDB Compass, первый раз пользуюсь этой БД, прошу помогите, вообще не понимаю в чем проблема.
